# Как отключить открытие клавиатуры при изменении input?

Tags: jquery-ui, touch

Использую jquery ui slider когда смещаю ползунок, в поле input выводится значение на котором находится ползунок, на touch устройствах в этот момент открывается клавиатура, как от этого избавиться? 
[Ссылка на демострацию](http://school-calculator.webflow.io/)

Comment: event.preventDefault() не помогает?

Comment: @BimBam, если добавить event.preventDefault() ползунок остается на одном месте но клавиатура открывается

Comment: А попробуй в инпут вставить readonly="true"

Comment: @BimBam, да это решит проблему, но этот атрибут нужно только на мобильные добавлять, на десктопной версии нужен ввод с клавиатуры

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить простое и легковесное решение. (Vue, Angular, React,etc - на свой вкус)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: '50'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <p>{{ message }} рублей</p>
  <input type=range v-model="message">
</div>
```

Comment: Это можно сделать и на jquery с помощью триггера change, собственно там это и реализовано, на данный момент воспользовался предложением @BimBam, в котором он советовал добавить readonly + у vue какая-то сложная кастюмизация в сравнении с jquery Ui